# Setting hit policy in drools decision table through java

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I am working on poc where i need to set hit policy for decision table here the decision table is in xls format.
Can anyone have the previous experience of this and let me know how can i resolve this one.

environment:-Eclipse IDE,Java,Drools 7, Decision table in xls format